# Private aks and acr in different resource group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-acr

I want to have a zero-trust infrastructure, so I need to have `aks` and `acr` completely independent and just have a connection for pulling the images. I created a private `aks` through the azure portal(assign specific vnet to it), and create a private `acr` too(without principal service). Then I add `acrPull` role for `aks` in `acr` access roles, and after that I add private access through the networking part of `acr` between them. Unfortunately, when I try `az aks check-acr` command it returns:

```
Validating image pull permission: FAILED
[2022-01-19T14:00:37Z] ACR containerregistrymaryam.azurecr.io rejected token exchange: ACR token exchange endpoint returned error status: 403. body:
```

The current state of permissions and connection is as below:
[image: access roles]
[image: resource visualizers]
If you have any clue for me please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the assign the role `AcrPull` to the Kubelet Identity of your node pool and not to the AKS Identity:

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export ACR_ID=$(az acr show -g <resource group> -n <acr name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "AcrPull" --scope $ACR_ID
```

Comment: thanks but as I explained in my question I have it and it's not enough!

Comment: You said = Then I add acrPull role for aks in acr access roles. AKS Identity and Kubelet Identity are different Identities. Its not so easy to assign the Kubelet Identity over the portal. So maybe you check againt that you assigned to correct identity or you share more details like code or screenshots from your config!

Comment: Aha, I got what did you mean! Thanks! I tried it and it didn't work for me. I added a screenshot of the config, please take a look and if you have any idea let me know.